# Table/list: find the last real number element of each row to constitute a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list (`Table`), mostly composed of real numbers. The list also contains some non-real elements. The list is similar to the following (but much much larger):

```
{{0.11011887269, 0.02087291466, 0.02082444233, 0.02083704779, 
  0.02084940959, 0.02086181292, 0.02087425501, 0.02088673503, 
  0.02089925331, 0.02091181001, 0.02092440529, 0.02093703933, 
  0.02094971232, 0.02096242441, test1[18, 15]}, {0.10941526373, 
  0.017604005802, 0.017549654594, 0.017558686829, test1[19, 5], 
  test1[19, 6], test1[19, 7], test1[19, 8], test1[19, 9], 
  test1[19, 10], test1[19, 11], test1[19, 12], test1[19, 13], 
  test1[19, 14], test1[19, 15]}, {0.10890647143, 0.014986243752, 
  0.014927392616, 0.014934004368, test1[20, 5], test1[20, 6], 
  test1[20, 7], test1[20, 8], test1[20, 9], test1[20, 10], 
  test1[20, 11], test1[20, 12], test1[20, 13], test1[20, 14], 
  test1[20, 15]}}
```

I would like to construct a single row or column list that **preserves the last real number element of each row** of the above list. For example, with the above table, the resulting list should contain only 3 elements as:

```
{0.02096242441, 0.017558686829, 0.014934004368}
```

How can this resulting list be automatically constructed from the original one?

Comment: How about `Table[Last[Cases[row, _Real]], {row, d}]` where `d` is your list

Comment: @MelaGo This is exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `table` your list of lists:

```
Cases[table, {___, a_?NumericQ, Except[_?NumericQ] ...} :> a, All]
```

> ```
> {0.0209624, 0.0175587, 0.014934}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
SequenceCases[list, {{__, a_Real, __test1}} -> a]
```

{0.0209624, 0.0175587, 0.014934}

Answer (score 2):

Using `SplitBy`:

```
Last@#1 & @@@ (SplitBy[#, Head] & /@ list)

(*{0.0209624, 0.0175587, 0.014934}*)
```

Or using `ReplaceList`:

```
ReplaceList[list, {___, s : {__, a_Real, __test1}, ___} :> a]

(*{0.0209624, 0.0175587, 0.014934}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using `Cases`:**

For each entry in `list` reversed, the `Cases` command can pick the first instance of `_Real`:

```
list = {{0.11011887269, 0.02087291466, 0.02082444233, 0.02083704779, 
    0.02084940959, 0.02086181292, 0.02087425501, 0.02088673503, 
    0.02089925331, 0.02091181001, 0.02092440529, 0.02093703933, 
    0.02094971232, 0.02096242441, test1[18, 15]}, {0.10941526373, 
    0.017604005802, 0.017549654594, 0.017558686829, test1[19, 5], 
    test1[19, 6], test1[19, 7], test1[19, 8], test1[19, 9], 
    test1[19, 10], test1[19, 11], test1[19, 12], test1[19, 13], 
    test1[19, 14], test1[19, 15]}, {0.10890647143, 0.014986243752, 
    0.014927392616, 0.014934004368, test1[20, 5], test1[20, 6], 
    test1[20, 7], test1[20, 8], test1[20, 9], test1[20, 10], 
    test1[20, 11], test1[20, 12], test1[20, 13], test1[20, 14], 
    test1[20, 15]}};

Cases[Reverse@#, _Real, 1, 1] & /@ list // Flatten[#, 1] &
```

---

*Result:*

> {0.0209624, 0.0175587, 0.014934}